# Manhwa where the female lead soul swaps with a noble lady before her execution

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

My description will be a little vague so I apologise in advance, but I've been trying to find this manhwa I read on and off, as it was in its early stages of releases.

What I remember is that the female lead (FL) was held in what looked like a prison and it seems like she lived a miserable life, especially with how she is due to be executed under false pretenses. Another character is introduced, a noble lady, and it seems like she is the reason that the FL who is about to be executed. One thing that stuck out to me is that the noble lady whispered about how she envied the FL because she would get to die.

Later, I don't remember how, the FL makes a deal with someone (I think), which leads to her soul entering the noble lady’s body and vice versa. Through this, we learn the "envy" the original noble lady felt made sense, as the first thing the FL goes through is getting eaten out by the butler, which was the first and last time that took place. This threw me off as I did not expect this but I was hooked.

I believe the original body of the FL was executed as scheduled and now the FL needs to be smart and careful about her life, as she needs to find out the people tied behind her planned arrest and execution. That is as far as I remember.

Something to note is that the art style was very cleanly done and attractive to look at. Forgive me for the vagueness. And the period it is set in is the standard timeline you would see in revenge/betrayal plots.

I hope someone can help me because I need to know what has happened since. Thank you.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead? Also, is the following line a reference to oral sex, or did you mean to say that the female lead was _chewed_ out by the butler, i.e. told off? _"getting eaten out by the butler"_

Comment: @LogicDictates My assumption was that it referred to the sex act. Wild guess, haven't read it so I can't confirm, but is this Depths of Malice?

Comment: @qazmlpok that's the name of the manhwa, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[Depths of Malice](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/depths-of-malice)*.

> After years of hardship that culminate in the form of a terminal illness, Rita is determined to do whatever it takes to survive. It might be the wrong thing to **steal somebody else’s body**, but she doesn’t care about what’s right or wrong anymore. Now, she’s Verta, the affluent and beautiful daughter of Count Alberhart. She’s in the prime position to enjoy a comfortable life…but the people around her seem intent on breaking her. Well, she’s happy to crush whoever gets in her way. It’s time for them to learn how deep her malice goes…

The synopsis mentions the body swap. The prologue chapter has the original body's owner state that she's envious of the protagonist, as the protagonist is terminally ill. I don't believe she's sentenced to death.

[image]

The end of the prologue has her accepting an offer to swap bodies; chapter 1 and beyond is after the body swap.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd remember random scenes with no context once every blue moon. I appreciate you and the commenter @qazmlpok. I got worried about how vauge my question was but ended up getting helped out. Thanks again.

Comment: @AStoryIOnceRead You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the asker's satisfaction.